# Sort a list of strings by index

Tags: python

i have a text file full of symbols and numbers all as string. I am trying to move it over in another list where it sorts after the index number. But i am new at python, and not really sure how to do this. I have in my "a" made i tuple and seperated the int from the string. I now want to sort on the ints.

```
sortedlist = []
with open("m_scrambled.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
            a = (int(line.partition(" ")[0]),line.partition(" ")[2])
            b=sorted(a)
            print(a)
```

the error i am getting by trying to sort on "a".

> ```
> '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
> ```

a snippet of the file, i hope you can help me getting smarter on this!

``````````````````
150                                                                                                                                  
139                                        ,W@@@@@@@@@####*;;####@@@W@@@@##Wii;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::,,,,,,,,,:::
140                                        .xWW@@W@@@@##W+;;;;+W@@WWWWW@@##Wi;i;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::::::::::;;;::
141                                        `+@@@@@@@####Wii;;;iW###@@@@@###ni;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::,,,...``
138                                    `,;*n@@@@@@########i:;x###@@@@######@#;iii;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::,,..```...
146                                   .#xxxMWWWW@#######@n#++#n@#######@@WMMWWWWz;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:,.``                         
137                                 `:+zxMMMMMMMMMMWW@@##@:,,x##############W*iii;;;i;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::,,..```   
147                                 ``.+W@@@@@@@####Wxnz++****++znxW####@@@@@#@@z*iiii;;;;;;ii;;;;:,.``                              
142                                 `````.iM############Wi;;;;*W############M+;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:,,...``       
136                               `;+zzznnxnnnnnnnxxxxxMMMxxxMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWWWWMxz+i;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::,,,..``    
148                               ``.,;nW@@@@@@@@Wxz+*iii;;;;iii**+#nMW@@@@@@@@@x+*ii;;:::,,,..``                                    
149                               ```.:;+zzzz#+i:,.````  ``````````..,:;i+##zz#+;:..``                                               
135                              `*##zzzzzzzzzzznnxxMxxxxnnnnxxxxxxxxxMMxxxMMMMMMMMMMx#i;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::,,...``      
134                             `*+####zzzz#zzzznnnxxxxxnnnnnnnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMxxxxxMMMx#i;;;;i;;i;i;;;;;;;;;;;;::::,,,..````        
132                            :+#+####zzz#zzznzzzzzzzz#####zzznnnnnnnzzznnnnnnnxxxxxxxxxxxi`````````````````                        
145                            ``.,,,,:*xxMW@@@@#########niii*x@#######@@WMMW@@M+;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:,..`                     
133                            `i+#####zzz##zznnnnnznzzzzzzzznnnnnnnnxxnnnnxxxxxxxxxxxxxMxi:::::::::::::::,,,,,....`````             
130                           :+++####################zzzzzzzzznnnnzznnnzzzznnnzznnnnnnnnnxxx,                                       
131                           `*+#+#######zzzzz####zz#####z##zzzzzzzzzzzzznznnnnnnnnnxnnnnxxi                                        
143                           `..,::;;;;in##############@*;;;;+@#############@ni;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::,,.```            
128                          ,****++++++++++++#######zzznnnnzzzzznnxxxnnnnnzznnnn#zxnzzznWWWWMi                                      
127                          ;i****++++++*++#z###zzzzz#zz##zzzzzzzzznnxnnnzzzznnxn#xnzznMWMxxxz`
``````````````````

Comment: You are currently trying to sort partitions, not lines. Construct another list by appending `a` to it inside your `for` loop and then sort that second list.

Comment: @Selcuk i tried that, saying sortedList.append(a). but when i print it, i will only get a lot of "none, none, none etc.."

Comment: You could use a `dict` with key as your integer part and value as string.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r - Dictionaries are ordered in insertion order so how would that sort them?

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for pointing out. Didn't knew with 3.7+ , dict retain insertion order.

Comment: @Sayse So why is it "none" when i append to a new list?

Comment: @fallenmcmullan Does the data source actually contain the `>` characters and are the items in brackets always split over multiple lines? `sorted` accepts a key, which allows you to specify a function which tells sorted how to sort the data rather than the default way. Provide a cleaner version of the source data and I might be able to help

Comment: @scotty3785 No the text, does not have the ">"  :)
Yes they are always split. 

okay i will send a more detailed version

Comment: Is it possible that you did something like `lst = lst.append(a)`? That would explain the `None`s...

Comment: @Tomerikoo "b = sortedList.append(a)". and it throws me "none"

Comment: `list.append` changes the list and does not generate and return a new list. So `sortedList.append(a)` appends to `sortedList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a regular expression to find the number at the start of each line and use this as the method for python to sort

```
import re

def sortByLeadingNumber(line):
    matches = re.match("^[\d]+", line)[0]
    return int(matches)

with open('scrambled_file.txt') as file:
    sortedLines = list(sorted(file.readlines(),key=sortByLeadingNumber))

print(sortedLines)
```

If you don't want to use regular expressions, a slightly less robust method would be the following which just splits the line up by space characters and uses the first item as a number to sort by

```
def sortByLeadingNumberNoRe(line):
    return int(line.split()[0])
```

You'd then use this as the `key` argument to `sorted`.

Comment: What if i were not to use "re" ?

Comment: I get the error "'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'"

Comment: @fallenmcmullan Niklas is correct. It should be readlines. I've changed my answer. I'll add a non-re method too

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Thanks for spotting that! I was re-writing my answer to handle reading from a file rather than a string as you commented.

Comment: Output looks like ascii art of a tellytubbies legs!